# conway game of life neighbor issue(java)

Tags: java, arrays, conways-game-of-life

I'm currrently having issues with the neighbors in my project where i have to modify two diffrent methods for a conway game of life. My TA says my code looks like it should work but the neightbor count isn't working. I'v been printing the neightbor code and it works for the first time than it just goes to 0 for the rest of the run. Anyone have an idea where I am messing up?

```
public static void updateLife(Boolean[][] gameCellAlive) {
int size = gameCellAlive.length;
System.out.println("size of temp--->"+size);
Boolean[][] tempCell = new Boolean [size][size];
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
for (row = 0; row<tempCell.length; row++) {
for(col=0; col<tempCell[0].length; col++) {
tempCell[row][col] = gameCellAlive[row][col];
}
}   
for (int i = 0; i<tempCell.length; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j<tempCell[0].length; j++) {
int tempInt = getLifeNeighborCount(gameCellAlive, j, i);
System.out.println("neighbors---->"+tempInt);
if  ((tempInt>3) || (tempInt<2)) {
tempCell[i][j] = false;
}
else if(tempInt == 3) {
tempCell[i][j] = true;
}
else if(tempInt==2) {
tempCell[i][j]=true;
}
/*else {
tempCell[row][col]=gameCellAlive[row][col];
}*/

}//2nd for loop
}//for loop

for (int x = 0; x<tempCell.length; x++) {
for(int y=0; y<tempCell[0].length; y++) {
gameCellAlive[x][y] = tempCell[x][y];
}
}

  // METHOD STUB - This method needs to be implemented!
//if statemeent for requirements.
} // end method updateLife

/**
 *
 * @param gameBoard A 2D boolean array containing the current life status of
 * each cell at each x,y coordinate on the board. true indicates that the
 * cell is alive. false indicates no life in that cell.
 * @param colIndex The x position of the cell in the game board whose
 * neighbors are to be counted.
 * @param rowIndex The y position of the cell in the game board whose
 * neighbors are to be counted.
 * @return the number of cells adjacent to the cell at the specified row and
 * column that contain life. This value ranges between 0 (no adjacent cells
 * contain life) and 8 (all adjacent cells contain life).
 *
 * CS1180 Note: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD
 */
public static int getLifeNeighborCount(Boolean[][] gameBoard, int colIndex, int rowIndex) {
    // METHOD STUB - THIS METHOD NEEDS TO BE IMPLEMENTED
    int neighborCount = 0;

    //check for alive or dead
    for (int i = rowIndex-1; i<=rowIndex+1; i++) {
    for (int j = colIndex-1; j<=rowIndex+1; j++) {
    try {
    if (gameBoard[i][j]==true  && (i !=rowIndex || j!=colIndex)) {
    //System.out.println("hello");
    neighborCount++;
    }//end if
    }//end try

    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){         
    }//end catch
    }//end second foor loop
    }//end first foor loop
    return neighborCount;
    }// end method getLifeNeighborCount
```

Comment: I can't read your code -- please improve its formatting.

Comment: Every time a programmer writes an empty `catch` clause a baby panda dies...

Comment: Everytime a guy on the internet makes a pointless comment.

Comment: http://www.reactionface.info/sites/default/files/imagecache/Node_Page/images/1314029819767.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong variable in the condition in this loop:

```
for (int j = colIndex-1; j<=rowIndex+1; j++) {
```

It should be:

```
for (int j = colIndex-1; j<=colIndex+1; j++) {
```